# How to iterate list in mongodb $lookup and pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections i.e parent and chilednodes.

```
 {
    "_id" : "5e6cd8c1996ddf1c28e14505",
    "parentList" : [
        {
            "_id" : "5e6c70e8996ddf1c28e14504",
            "startDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
            "active_id" : "child_vesrion_1",
            "child_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf30"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "5e6c70e8996ddf1c28e14506",
            "startDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
            "active_id" : "child_vesrion_1",
            "child_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf31"
        }
    ]
}
```

And childnodes are;

```
{
    "_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf31",
    "startDate" : "2020-03-25T14:01:58.697Z",
    "endDate" : null,
    "child_vesrion_1" : {
        "childName" : "test3",
        "createdDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
        "text" : "test3 text",
        "type" : "test3 type"
    },
    "child_vesrion_2" : {
        "childName" : "Test4",
        "createdDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
        "text" : "test4 text",
        "type" : "test4 type"
    },
    "active" : "child_vesrion_1"
},
{
    "_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf30",
    "startDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
    "endDate" : null,
    "child_vesrion_1" : {
        "childName" : "test1",
        "createdDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
        "text" : "test1 text",
        "type" : "test1 type"
    },
    "child_vesrion_2" : {
        "childName" : "test2",
        "createdDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
        "text" : "test2 text",
        "type" : "test2 type"
    },
    "active" : "child_vesrion_1"
}
```

Here is my query;

```
db.parent.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id": "5e6cd8c1996ddf1c28e14505" } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "childnodes",
            let: { "child_id": "$parentList.child_id", "activeid": "$parentList.active_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { "$expr": { $eq: ["$_id", "$$child_id"] } } },
                {
                    $project: {
                        "child_id": "$_id",
                        "start_date": "$startDate",
                        "current_version_Key": "$active",
                        "active_child_name": {
                            "$reduce": {
                                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                                "initialValue": "",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$this.k", "$$activeid"] },
                                        "$$this.v.childName",
                                        "$$value"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "text": {
                            "$reduce": {
                                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                                "initialValue": "",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$this.k", "$$activeid"] },
                                        "$$this.v.text",
                                        "$$value"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "$reduce": {
                                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                                "initialValue": "",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$this.k", "$$activeid"] },
                                        "$$this.v.type",
                                        "$$value"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "finalList",
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
          parentList: 0,
        },
      },
]);
```

I am expecting results like;

```
{
  "_id": "5e6cd8c1996ddf1c28e14505",
  "finalList": [
    {
      "child_id": "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf30",
      "start_date": "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
      "current_version_Key": "child_vesrion_1",
      "active_child_name": "test1",
      "text": "test1 text",
      "type": "test1 type",

    },
    {
      "child_id": "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf31",
      "start_date": "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
      "current_version_Key": "child_vesrion_1",
      "active_child_name": "test3",
      "text": "test3 text",
      "type": "test3 type",

    }
  ]
}
```

But i am not getting anything in finalList. It is returning an empty array.

I have tried with different approaches but it didn't help me. I am bit new to mongodb,  any help on this would be appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were so close. Your `parentList` is an array, so when you define `child_id` and `activeid` inside `$lookup`, they are also array.

If we add `$unwind` before the `$lookup` + `$group` at the end, your query works as expected.

Try this one:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": "5e6cd8c1996ddf1c28e14505"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$parentList"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "childnodes",
      let: {
        "child_id": "$parentList.child_id",
        "activeid": "$parentList.active_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "$expr": {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$child_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            child_version: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: {
                      $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
                    },
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.k",
                        "$$activeid"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "child_id": "$_id",
            "start_date": "$startDate",
            "current_version_Key": "$active",
            "active_child_name": "$child_version.v.childName",
            "text": "$child_version.v.text",
            "type": "$child_version.v.type"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "finalList"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$finalList"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      parentList: {
        $push: "$finalList"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WitMv6dxRvE)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @valijon. I am  trying to optimize this code. Is there any way i can optimise $reduce method? given that i need all 3 value from child table(active_child_name, type, text)

Comment: @SwagathShatty I've updated my answer with optimised code.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I appreciate your help  :)

Comment: Thanks for your support @valijon. It looks like the "let" which we have under $lookup is not supporting in azure cosmos db. I am trying to rewrite this query without using let. 
But it is getting more complex. Is there any way we can rewrite this query without using "let" ?

Comment: @SwagathShatty try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bka9M0UGRc2)